# SQL Splitting Row with start and end times into two rows, over an arbitrary splitting time

Tags: sql, time, view, ssms

I have data for events with a start and end time. Sometimes the event straddles midnight and I want to split the event into two separate events. As an example, I would like to split this: (note: the dates are MM-DD-YYYY)

```
StartTime                EndTime                  Duration     EventID
12-14-2022 1:46:00AM     12-14-2022 5:51:00AM     245          11122
12-14-2022 9:38:00AM     12-15-2022 12:06:00AM    148          11123
12-15-2022 5:22:00PM     12-16-2022 3:30:00AM     608          11124
12-16-2022 3:00:00AM     12-17-2022 4:00:00AM     1500         11125
```

Into this

```
StartTime                EndTime                  Duration     EventID
12-14-2022 1:46:00AM     12-14-2022 5:51:00AM     245          11122
12-14-2022 9:38:00PM     12-15-2022 12:00:00AM    142          11123
12-15-2022 12:00:00AM    12-15-2022 12:06:00AM    6            11123
12-15-2022 5:22:00PM     12-16-2022 12:00:00AM    398          11124
12-16-2022 12:00:00AM    12-16-2022 3:30:00AM     210          11124
12-16-2022 3:00:00AM     12-17-2022 12:00:00AM    1260         11125
12-17-2022 12:00:00AM    12-17-2022 4:00:00AM     240          11125
```

Note, the possibility of overlaps as shown in the third and fourth events.

I would show you my attempt, but frankly, I don't know how to begin. I would normally just use python to do something like this, but the nature of the project and the regulations at my company prevent that.

(I actually don't need the split to happen at midnight, but at 7:00 am for some tables and 6:30am for others. So bonus points if your solution can handle an arbitrary split time. But I'm sure I can work that out if you give me the base case.)

Comment: Please TAG your DBMS and add your table schema

Comment: Added the tags. DBMS is SSMS. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by schema, I'm a light SQL user, not much of a developer. I believe the StartTime is linked to a Date Table, if that's important.

Comment: `SSMS` is not a database - it's a client GUI that you use to connect to a database - that could Be SQL Server, SQL Azure DB, Azure Managed Instance, Azure Synapse etc. `schema` ie the *create table* object.

Comment: I assume Sequel server. As for the schema, If I understand you (and google) correctly, then I am dealing with dbos and views (this particular issue shows up in a variety of places). I neither made the DB, nor do I have direct access to it. I'm just trying to figure out a query that will handle it so my coworkers can stop manually splitting the events on decade old Access apps.